# Error in JSF project: Getting error in faces-config.xml

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

I am getting error in my face-config.xml file

```
Cannot resolve the name 'javaee:descriptionGroup' to a(n) 'group' 
     component.
    -21 changed lines
```

I don't know how.. everything was working fine earlier. I don't know what I edited now I am getting this error.

Here are the content of my XML (faces-config.xml) file:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <application>
        <!--Configuration for supporting i18N -->
        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>en</default-locale>
            <supported-locale>fr</supported-locale>
        </locale-config>
        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>messages</base-name>
            <var>messages</var>
        </resource-bundle>
    </application>
</faces-config>
```

Help me out to resolve this.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to validate your file with some online validator or the one in your IDE. Maybe you have accidentally changed something...And also look at the your xml schema if it's set right

Comment: add the content of faces-config, otherwise it will be difficuly to help you

Comment: Yes, please show the root declaration of `faces-config.xml`. Also, have you recently installed/changed a JAXP based XML parser like Xerces, Xalan, etc at JDK or servletcontainer level? Or have you recently changed the `web.xml` and/or the servletcontainer? This error suggests that the XML parser don't recognize the `javaee` schema location as specified in `xsi:schemaLocation`.

Comment: @Balus- I have recently installed 'Rinzo XML Editor Core' plugin in my eclipse. Is that a problem ???

Comment: Your `faces-config.xml` looks fine. The chance is very reasonable that this plugin is the cause of this problem. Perhaps it has changed the default JAXP parser or its settings. I have however never used this plugin, so I can't tell from experience.